# renorm a Banach space to make an operator have spectral radius equal to norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional complex Banach space equipped with the norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$, and let $T\in\mathcal{L}(X)$ a bounded linear operator on $X$.  Let $r(T)$ denote the spectral radius of $T$, and suppose $r(T)<\lVert T\rVert$.  I would like to renorm $X$ with an equivalent norm $|\cdot|$ so that $r(T)=|T|$, i.e. so that the spectral radius attains the operator norm.

It is already known that we can equivalently renorm $X$ so that the spectral radius *almost* attains the norm.  Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary and let $m$ be the smallest integer so that $\lVert T^m\rVert^{1/m}<r(T)+\epsilon$.  Then we can define the equivalent norm $|\cdot|_{T,\epsilon}$ on $X$ by

$\displaystyle |x|_{T,\epsilon}:=\left[\lVert x\rVert^2+\left(\frac{\lVert Tx\rVert}{r(T)+\epsilon}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\lVert T^2x\rVert}{[r(T)+\epsilon]^2}\right)^2+\cdots+\left(\frac{\lVert T^mx\rVert}{[r(T)+\epsilon]^m}\right)^2\right]^{1/2}$

In this case, $|T|_{T,\epsilon}<r(T)+\epsilon$.  However, this is not good enough for my purposes.  We need equality, not almost-equality.

In general, what I want need not be possible, for instance if $T$ is a nonzero quasinilpotent operator.  However, this problem arises in a context where I can make some powerful assumptions.  In particular, I have a situation where $0<r(T)$ with $\sigma(T)$ uncountable, $0\in\partial\sigma(T)$, and $\partial\sigma(T)\subseteq\sigma_p(T)$, where $\sigma(T)$ denotes the spectrum and $\sigma_p(T)$ the point spectrum, and $\partial$ denotes the topological boundary.  I can also assume that $\sigma_p(T^*)=\emptyset$, where $T^*\in\mathcal{L}(X^*)$ is the continuous dual of $T$.

At least sometimes, what I want really is possible.  For instance let $(\delta_n)$ be a strictly decreasing sequence of positive reals with $\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+\delta_n)<\infty$, and let $T\in\mathcal{L}(c_0)$ be the weighted left-shift operator defined by $Te_1=0$ and $Te_{n+1}=(1+\delta_n)e_n$, where $(e_n)$ is the unit vector basis for $c_0$, and $c_0$ (as usual) is the space of scalar sequences tending to zero equipped with the sup norm.  Then it's easy to see that $1=r(T)<1+\delta_1=\lVert T\rVert$.  Now, let $U\in\mathcal{L}(c_0)$ be the isomorphism $Ue_n=(1+\delta_n)e_n$, and define $|\cdot|$ by $|x|:=\lVert U^{-1}x\rVert$.  Then $|\cdot|$ is an equivalent norm with $r(T)=|T|=1$.

Has this problem been studied at all?

Please note, I am also free to "adjust" $X$ by modding out finite-dimensional subspaces.  More precisely, if $F$ is a finite-dimensional subspace of $X$ then I can replace $X$ with $W\cong X/F$, where $X=W\oplus F$ and $T$ with the corresponding induced operator $P_WT|_W$ (where $P_W$ is the continuous linear projection onto $W$ along $F$).

Comment: For the last paragraph, $F$ has to be $T$-invariant for this to make sense.

Comment: Oh, sorry for not being clear about that.  Fixed.

Comment: Just to check: you have an operator $T\in X\to Y$, where $X=Y$.  You want to change the norm on $Y$ but not $X$, right?

Comment: @JacobManaker Since OP writes $T\in\mathcal L(X)$, we have $Y=X$.